# ASP.NET Web API message handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to implement my custom message handler that will check for a custom header that must be present in every request.

If my custom header is present the request passes through and will hit the controller if the header is not there the request is rejected with custom error message.

No my question is: if I implement my handler that way that means all requests MUST have the header however I need to have a `gate` where I can call without that header and the request must be ignored by message handler and hit the controller even without the custom header.

Is it possible to achieve this? Or how can I implement my message handler that will ignore certain calls to specific controller or something like this ...?

Comment: You could probably use authorization filters or `route-specific` message handlers in this case.

Comment: I don't see this gate thing can be done. because if you implement this check for custom header in "http handler" or "http module" or as "action filter". It will run for all calls. Maybe you can add another condition like if a certain query string or cookie exists then it is okay not to have the custom header

Comment: In fact @KiranChalla is right, you can implement route-specific message handler like here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.. (untested)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;


 public abstract class EnforceMyBusinessRulesController : ApiController
{

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {

        /*

            Use any of these to enforce your rules;

            http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

            Public property Configuration   Gets or sets the HttpConfiguration of the current ApiController.
            Public property ControllerContext   Gets the HttpControllerContext of the current ApiController.
            Public property ModelState  Gets the model state after the model binding process.
            Public property Request Gets or sets the HttpRequestMessage of the current ApiController.
            Public property Url Returns an instance of a UrlHelper, which is used to generate URLs to other APIs.
            Public property User    Returns the current principal associated with this request. 
        */

        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        bool iDontLikeYou = true; /* Your rules here */
        if (iDontLikeYou)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }


    }

}



public class ProductsController : EnforceMyBusinessRulesController
{

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    }


}
```

Comment: I think this is a complex approach for the stuff that the user is asking for.

Comment: I hear ya.  Provide a simple(r) response, and I'll upvote it!  I'm all for learning something new.